# Как в переменной ansible указать список хостов?

Tags: ansible, zabbix

Пишу плейбук для автоматизации добавления хостов на zabbix-сервер. В файле с переменными есть переменная zabbix_hostname: которой должен быть присвоен список ip для добавления на zabbix-сервер

```
zabbix_hostname:
  - 10.1.1.1
  - 10.1.1.2
```

и т.д. С одним IP работает, со списком не получается - все ip почему-то преобразуются в строку. Как правильно прописать список?

Comment: Где и как используется эта переменная?

Comment: Используется в файле default/main.yml вместе с другими zabbix_admin_user: Admin
zabbix_admin_password: zabbix
zabbix_server: "127.0.0.1"
zabbix_server_https: false
zabbix_proxy: ""
zabbix_host_groups: "{{ group_names | difference('ungrouped') }}"
zabbix_hostname: "{{ inventory_hostname }}" - тут должен быть список IP
zabbix_host_ip: "{{ hostvars[inventory_hostname].ansible_host | default('0.0.0.0')  }}"

Comment: В файле default/main.yml она не используется, а просто создаётся. А используется-то где?

Comment: - name: Add host to zabbix
  local_action:
    module: zabbix_host
    server_url: "{{ zabbix_url }}"
    login_user: "{{ zabbix_admin_user }}"
    login_password: "{{ zabbix_admin_password }}"
    host_name: "{{ zabbix_hostname }}"

Comment: Заглядывая в [документацию модуля zabbix_host](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/community/zabbix/zabbix_host_module.html#parameter-host_name), видим, что параметр `host_name` может быть только строкой и никакие списки не допускаются

Comment: Тогда не понятно какой в этом модуле смысл, если хосты приходится добавлять по одному :(

Comment: Фиг знает какой конкретно результат вам нужен, но как минимум всегда можно запустить таску [в цикле по списку](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_loops.html)

Comment: Стоп. А разве ip\адреса прописываются не в inventory? Ну согласно архитектуре.

Answer (score 0):

Решил вопрос массового добавления хостов с помощью соответствующей коллекции для работы с zabbix.